# Finding the number of points that lie within a radius of another point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer, proximity

I'm trying to find the number of restaurants that lie within 500m of a grocery store. I'm so confused as to how to do this. Using the near tool, it seems to only find the closest one. I tried generating a near table, but I was having trouble understanding that the different columns were.

Sometimes there are grocery stores closer than 500m apart, so I only want to count the restaurants that are closest to that grocery store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate Near Table is correct. For input features, select your grocery points, for near features, select the restaurant points. Uncheck the box that says, find only closest feature.

Your table will look something like IN_FID (original input feature ObjectID) NEAR_FID (near features ObjectID) NEAR_DIST (distance in whatever unit your projection uses)

You can weed out which ones are within your 500m distance.

Comment: "for near features, select the same points" so the restaurant points again? why isn't it the grocery store points?

Comment: Oh yea just noticed that, edited the response

Comment: Thanks. Which part tells me how many how many restaurants are near that grocery store?

Comment: The near table should have every combination of features. Every grocery store with every restaurant and given distance. You can select all values less than 500m or so, then summarize by the input feature (grocery stores) and it should give you the counts per grocery story.

Comment: I'm having trouble summarizing it. So I add a field, then I click summarize. Do I select In_FID for "select a field to summarize"? And then "choose a summarty statistic to be included in the output table", which is it? Thank you!

Comment: Right click the IN_FID field, click summarize, leave the default options and press OK. This should return a table of unique IN_FIDs and the number of occurrences

Comment: It returns "output name not valid". It was automatically saving as .dbf, should it be something else?

Comment: probably some character you used that you cannot, name it something simple just to test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49121/discussion-between-j-doe-and-maksim).